# OpenERP V7 - Button Action

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using OpenERP V7,need some basic helps. Added a new icon in POLine

Create new Xml,py file under Wizard in Purchase Module.

**add.xml** code:

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="add_slab_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Add Slab</field>
        <field name="model">add.slab</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Add Slab" version="7.0">                  
                <footer>
                    <button name="add_info" string="Add" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    or
                    <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
                </footer>
            </form>             
        </field>
    </record>       
    <record id="add_slab_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">

    </record>               
</data>
```

Form view get installed and i cant see the action view.

**Button Action Code called in purchase_view.xml file**

```
<button name="%(add_slab_action)d" icon="gtk-add"  string="Add Slab" type="action"/>
```

add.py

```
 def add_slab_action(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    return {
          'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',

}
```

I got an error : **ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: purchase.add_slab_action**

Button Action is not performing ,How do i resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Do check this whether you have added your wizard file in **openerp**.py file.

Comment: Hmmm..!! Thatz what I have told you to chek it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is code you written in the button function?

for your information i show you one example here :

Like

```
<button name="%(stock.move_scrap)d"
string="Scrap Products" type="action"
icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-ltr" context="{'scrap': True}"
states="draft,waiting,confirmed,assigned"/>
```

Here in the button code you can see in the name of button is the action of wizard to open form to get data,  so you have to define some thing like that to open a form or from button function you have to return some other object form action to open from to get data like

```
return {
                'name': _('Distribution Model Saved'),
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'tree,form',
                'res_model': 'analytic.plan.create.model',
                'views': [(resource_id,'form')],
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'target': 'new',
            }
```

Hope this help

Comment: i think this action define any other module, for this you have to do some thins like this <button name=**"%(module_name.acion_name)d"** icon="gtk-add"  string="Add Slab" type="action"/>